# Stream host - developer prespective question

Tags: performance, streaming, video-streaming

Without many details, I have a request to develop a live stream service web site.

I do see it quite hard to archive on a shared host environment, due to bandwidth constrains.

Free webservices lack on speed and are more related to individuals that want to publish content online and not, sites that may want to use their services.

Is there any sort of service that we may considered, specific for streaming proposes?

I do believe a private host could be a very expensive choice.

I do believe someone here as already deal with streaming videos somehow, so, can I request some advices on considering the server options here ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you got a design? do you know your audience, player, codec, DRM, geolocations, content store size, live feed formats etc?

Comment: I don't want a specific solution for my problem. I want to understand the options that one may have, while opting for a live stream site development project. Generally speaking. Thanks. :)